# Why do I get different tags/elements results when searching different books on Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

Has anyone experienced different xml tag/element results when using amazon's API? If yes, how can I get the information I want if it is different from book to book?

**Case:**
I am trying to get the number of pages of the books that I am looking up. For the most part, it works okay with the following xml fetch:

```
$base->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->NumberOfPages
```

However, when I searched book with ISBN 0743234804, I would need to query the following to get the page number:

```
 $base->Items->Item[1]->ItemAttributes->NumberOfPages
```

This is quite unreliable, especially if there are other cases. How do you go about this problem?

** Updated the question - changed the query that would produce the correct page information **

Comment: Isn't `$base->Items->Item->ItemAttributes...` the same as `$base->Items->Item[0]->ItemAttributes...`?  If so, then the question should be answerable by examining the XML to determine why you sometimes need the first item element and other times you need the second.  You should then be able to find the right place to look, programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there may be multiple different types of the same book (hardcover/softcover/kindle?) and hence amazon will provide multple tags of .

The problem is that some of those  tags do not have all the ItemAttributes. But one them allow has the NumberOfPages that I wanted.

Solution: 
 Just loop through the  tags and check if it has the NumberOfPages element and if it does then assign it to a variable:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    if(@$base->Items->children()[$i]->ItemAttributes->NumberOfPages){
         $amazonprice = @$base->Items->children()[$i]->ItemAttributes->NumberOfPages;
    }
}
```